# Python - if/elif statements not working for KBS

Tags: python

I have simple if/elif statements referencing some "facts" I have written but only the first statement is working (even when the order is changed). If someone could be able to point me in the right direction to get the others to work, that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
facts = {
    'name' : 'Artificial Intelligence',
    'short-name' : 'AI',
    'about' : '...............................',
    'year' : '1943'}

running = True

while running:
    question_asked = str(input("\nWhat would you like to know?\n")).lower()

    if "name" in question_asked \
        and "artificial intelligence" in question_asked \
        and ("abbreviated" in question_asked \
        or "short" in question_asked):

        print("The abbreviated name for " + facts['name'] + \
            " is " + facts['short-name'])

#stops working here

    elif "name" in question_asked \
        and "AI" in question_asked \
        and ("full" in question_asked \
        or "long" in question_asked):

        print("The full name for " + facts['short-name'] + \
            " is " + facts['name'])

    elif ("first" in question_asked \
        or "original" in question_asked)\
        and "year" in question_asked \
        and ("AI" in question_asked \
        or "artificial intelligence" in question_asked):

        print(facts['short-name'] +  " was first widely recognised in " + \
            facts['year'])

    elif "about" in question_asked \
        and ("AI" in question_asked \
        or "artificial intelligence" in question_asked):

        print(facts['about'])

#works here again

 elif "end" in question_asked \
        or "exit" in question_asked \
        or "quit" in question_asked \
        or 'q' in question_asked \
        or len(question_asked) == 0:

        running = False

    else:
        print("I have no knowledge or I'm not sure what you mean.")
```

Comment: all subsequent `elif` blocks are not executed if a preceeding `if`/`elif` block was executed

Comment: What is "KBS" here?

Comment: I have no idea what the logic behind this script is.

Comment: Try using nested if

Answer (score 4):

`question_asked` is lowercase, so it cannot include the text `AI`.

You should change anywhere it says `AI` to `ai` and it should work as intended :)